# Spring boot 3.0.1 Actuator HttpTraceRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.1 and I am trying to implement HttpTraceRepository in the app's config class:

```
   @Bean
        public HttpTraceRepository createTranceRepository() {
        return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
    }
```

I have declared the actuator dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I can't implement the HttpTraceRepository Bean, because the class no longer exist in the actuator package.
Is this by design or a possible bug?
Thank you.

Comment: What isn't there cannot be used instead use `InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository` which is the replacement. It isn't a bug it is deliberate.

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#httptrace-endpoint-renamed-to-httpexchanges) you need to use the `HttpExchangeRepository` instead of `HttpTraceRepository`. In your case that would be the `InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository`.

```java
@Bean
public InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository createTraceRepository() {
  return new InMemoryHttpExchangeRepository();
}
```